# How to get this effect with CSS3?

Tags: css, css-transitions, effect

Please, how can I get an effect like the one in the upper right menu, with just CSS3? (mouse over -> circle shrinks and fades in, mouse out -> circle expands and fades out)

http://wpkuzen.com/html/architex/

I tried to look at the code and it's messy, nand couldn' find a tutorial that explain this...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're probably getting marked down because your link doesn't appear to be working so it's not easy to get a demo of your required functionality.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/Development/IconHoverEffects/

Comment: Basically just a div with such rounded corners it's a circle. CSS3 animation the size of the div on hover

Comment: @Danield: your comment was very very helpful! Please make it as answer so I can accept it!

Comment: @Ivan - I just posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/30/simple-icon-hover-effects/) and [demo](http://tympanus.net/Development/IconHoverEffects/). They have very similar transitions/animations to the one which you need.

Here's an example:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Yhb2g/1/)**

Markup:

```
<a href="#set-3" class="hi-icon"></a>
```

### CSS

```
.hi-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    color: green;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.3s;
    transition: color 0.3s;
}

.hi-icon:before {
    content: "X"; /* place image here */
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 90px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}


.hi-icon:hover:after {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
    opacity: 0;
}
.hi-icon:after {
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;    
    padding: 2px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.3s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This effect is done by using the CSS transition. You have one property and instead of change that property instantly (on hover or fadeout) you change that property over time.

Here you have a nice link helping you to hopefully achive your goals. :)

[link to transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand your comment "I tried to look at the code and it's messy".

You have a fully indented CSS with comments !

directly copy-pasted from your link:

```
/* Positioning the icons and preparing for the animation*/
.nav i {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px transparent;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: box-shadow .6s ease-in-out;
    width:1.1em !important;
}   

/* Animate the box-shadow to create the effect */
.navbar .nav a:hover i,
.navbar .nav a:active i,
.navbar .nav a:focus i {        
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is only a part of the script, of course: I yet saw what you copy/pasted but the story is not all there, you can find references to .nav and .navbar (and their a, i and :hover stuff) all along the whole css'... That is, this copy/paste doesn't work right out of the box...